# Save file locally on Windows from Firebase Storage in Flutter Windows

Tags: windows, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I cannot find a way to download the files from Firebase Storage to Windows in Flutter Desktop app. Is there a way?

I tried a few plugins for Flutter application but they are not saving the file in PC, even though they have access to Storage file in Firebase!

Answer (score 0):

To download files from Firebase Storage to a Windows PC, you can use the Firebase CLI (Command Line Interface). Here's how to do it:

1. Install the Firebase CLI by following the instructions on the Firebase documentation.
2. Open a command prompt or terminal window and log in to your Firebase account by running the command "firebase login".
3. Navigate to the directory where you want to download the file by running the command "cd C:\path\to\directory".
4. To download a file from Firebase Storage, use the command "firebase storage:download". The command should look like this:

> firebase storage:download --project= {project-id} {path-to-file-in-firebase-storage} {path-to-download-location-on-local-machine}

For example, if you want to download a file called "example.txt" from the Firebase Storage bucket "my-bucket" and save it to the "C:\Downloads" directory on your local machine, the command should look like this:

> firebase storage:download --project=my-project gs://my-bucket/example.txt C:\Downloads\example.txt

5. Once the download is complete, you should be able to find the file in the directory you just specified in step 3.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I am talking about how to download the files in Flutter Desktop app. This method requires user to install the package on its PC and run it via command prompt. No relevant to my question.